# JS : press enter and go to the next input

Tags: javascript, php

(Sorry if my english is bad)
I try to make a little game where you have to answer question in inputs. When you valid with the key "Enter", next input appear, and a new question in.

It is complicated to explain, so I leave you the test URL : nicolaslorand.com/bac.php

Here is my a part of my code :

```
var i = 1;
var j = 2;

$('#input'+i).keypress(function(event) {

console.log('input actuel :'+i);
console.log('input suivant :'+j);

if (event.which == 13) {
    verification();
    console.log("Touche entrée");

 }
});

function verification(){

document.getElementById('input'+j).style.display = "block";
var index = $(".inputform").index(this) + 1;
$(".inputform").eq(index).focus();

var recup = document.getElementById('input'+i);
var verif = recup.value.toUpperCase();

var divLettre = document.getElementById('lettre');
var premiereLettre = divLettre.innerText || divLettre.textContent;

if ( verif.charAt( 0 ) === premiereLettre ) {
    $("#input"+i).addClass('trueanswer');
    i++; j++;
    scoreTotal++;

    console.log(i);console.log(j);
    }

else{
    $("#input"+i).addClass('falseanswer');
    i++; j++;

    console.log(i);console.log(j);
    }
```

With this code, when I press enter, next input appear, but I have to write in the first input so that my answer is verified by the function.

Comment: var index = $(".inputform").index(this) + 1; **this** refers to window object. it should be **i**

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this` inside function this refers to window object. i think you should use `i` instead of `this`

```
var index = $(".inputform").index(i) + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks ! I'm a beginner in JS, this is my first project. However, my second input still does not work